# Correct way of creating supervisord script for gunicorn? Django 1.6

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

Here is my gonicorn.conf, but I can't seem to get the command right. The command Im trying is working when I type it in the command line, but not as an Supervisor command.

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory = /home/USER/.virtualenvs/SITE/myApp/
command=/home/USER/.virtualenvs/SITE/bin/python /home/USER/.virtualenvs/SITE/myApp/manage.py run_gunicorn myApp.wsgi:application -c /home/USER/.virtualenvs/SITE/myApp/gunicorn.conf.py
user = USER
autostart = true
autorestart = true
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /home/USER/logs/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile = /home/USER/logs/gunicorn_err.log
```

What is the correct command for gunicorn?

Here is the error Im getting when I try to start gunicorn:

```
/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/helpers.py:5: DeprecationWarning: django.utils.simplejson is deprecated; use json instead.
  from django.utils import simplejson

2013-02-25 13:46:55 [3975] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.2
2013-02-25 13:46:55 [3975] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (3975)
2013-02-25 13:46:55 [3975] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2013-02-25 13:46:55 [3988] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3988
2013-02-25 13:46:55 [3988] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 485, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 103, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py", line 133, in load
    return mod.make_command_wsgi_application(self.admin_media_path)
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/django_wsgi.py", line 113, in make_command_wsgi_application
    reload_django_settings()
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/django_wsgi.py", line 109, in reload_django_settings
    logging_config_func(settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 503, in configure
    raise ValueError("dictionary doesn't specify a version")
ValueError: dictionary doesn't specify a version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 485, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 100, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 103, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/djangoapp.py", line 133, in load
    return mod.make_command_wsgi_application(self.admin_media_path)
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/django_wsgi.py", line 113, in make_command_wsgi_application
    reload_django_settings()
  File "/home/USERNAME/.virtualenvs/SITE/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/django_wsgi.py", line 109, in reload_django_settings
    logging_config_func(settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 503, in configure
    raise ValueError("dictionary doesn't specify a version")
ValueError: dictionary doesn't specify a version
```

Comment: Ok read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464533/gunicorn-supervisor-startup-error and tell me if it's work or not

Comment: Yes, that seem to do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[program:projectname_gunicorn_live]
command=/home/myusername/projectname-live/bin/django run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:1559
directory=/home/myusername/projectname-live/
user=myusername
autostart=True
autorestart=True
redirect_stderr=True
```

Link: https://gist.github.com/oaksakal/1143612

Another Link: [Gunicorn Supervisor Startup Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464533/gunicorn-supervisor-startup-error)

Comment: I dont have any file called django inside my bin folder. I have installed django from git.

Tried to point to the manage.py, but I get this error when I try to "manage.py run_gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:1559"

ValueError: dictionary doesn't specify a version

Comment: did you try my sample or did you modified it? I don't have more knowledge about this but try to run the sample above, just change the myusername and projectname

Comment: Yes, I tried your example, but with my username and projectname. But I don't think it will work on my setup when I don't have the "django" file inside my bin folder.

Comment: Ok I will just search it again for another solution

Answer (score 22):

That specific error can be fixed by adding this variable to your settings file.  I ran into this when upgrading a django project from Django 1.3 to Django 1.5.
(See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/ for more info)

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
}
```